# Javascript popup keeps coming back even I click OK

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a textbox subscribed to 2 events. oninput and onblur.  Both events have a javascript popup.  The issue is that when oninput opens the popup, onblur event is triggered and opens up another popup, which is expected. But I can not click away from the second popup.
Why is it happening ? What is the best solution.

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kmananth84/zpkg50xd/32/)

```js
function TestBlur() {
  alert('Blur');
}

function TestInput() {
  var x = $("#TextboxComments").val();
  if (x == 'test') {
    alert('input');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input type="text" Id="TextboxComments" onblur="TestBlur();" oninput="TestInput();">
```

Comment: Well - you already posted your answer... You get an input - so an alert.. that causes a blur - so an alert - that causes an input... so an alert... and round and round... Question is: why an alert? That requires interaction, just use console.log for things like this

Comment: I'm just curious... Why do you have two `<head>` tags? 

Comment: @riffnl - so input popup  is seen only once.  It is the blur popup that keeps coming back again and again

Comment: Yeah - as it should actually - just don't use alert for this, just use console.log to capture these events.. The alert is the culprit

Comment: @riffnl - true.  But the main intention is to provide few validation messages to the user.

Comment: When you have `test`, your test-alert(1) triggers, which triggers blur(1) - when you ok the test-alert(1), the browser puts your input back in the input, then runs the triggered blur(1) - as you were in the input, this then triggers blur(2) - so you ok blur(1) but blur(2) is already queued, blur(1) puts you back in the input then blur(2) runs which triggers blur(3)... etc

Comment: Validation should never be done using alerts.. Avoid alerts at any cost is my motto

Comment: As above, don't use `alert()`, use a javascript/css popup / dialog / toastr / slide-down-panel.

Comment: Even you want to use the alert. I would suggest you to call one function on another, with condition so it not triggered everytime.